# How to copy void pointer (C++) to byte[] (C#) (CLI)

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have a `byte[]` in my C# code and I need to pass it to the C++ side and fill it with a data from `void*`

I do it this way

C# side

```
byte[] copy;
m_Logic.CopyToArray(out copy);
//There is filled `copy` that I can use
```

C++ (CLI) side

```
    void Agent_CLI::CopyToArray([Out] array<unsigned char> ^% input)
    {
        std::vector<int> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        void * data_to_copy = data.data(); //TEST : my data to copy

        int data_size = (int)data.size();
        input = gcnew array<unsigned char>(data_size);
        memcpy(&input[0], data_to_copy, data_size * sizeof(unsigned char));
    }
```

but I get the error

> error C2664: 'void *memcpy(void *,const void *,::size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'cli::interior_ptr' to 'void *'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have input buffer and output buffer swapped?

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure that I got your idea... I don't have output buffer, just input one. Anyway why do you think they should be swapped?

Comment: You need two buffers.

Comment: You can't use memcpy() without pinning the array object, use `pin_ptr<>`.  But just easier to use [Marshal::Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_IntPtr_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [articles about pin_ptr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/pin-ptr-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160) it seem like `&input[0]` will produce a `interior_ptr`, i.e. a pointer to the data of a managed object. This is supported by the error message you are getting.

This seem to be convertible to a `pin_ptr` that pins the object, preventing it from being moved by the garbage collector, and this is also convertable to a pointer. The articles suggest this should be possible:

```
pin_ptr<Byte> p = &input[0];   // entire array is now pinned
unsigned char * cp = p;
```